# getting the hidden field value of clicked item in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am not able to get the hidden field value of the clicked item.

I followed [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988378/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-listview-item-which-is-clicked-in-android) to get the hidden value of the clicked listview item but
unable to get the value. I am getting `ClassCastException`.

The code -

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
   //////////list view on click
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View arg1,
      int position, long arg3) {

      String S = (String)view.getItemAtPosition(position); //This line gives exception
      System.out.println("TextView vehicleSrc>>"+S);


     //OR

    String itemSelected =  ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_source)).getText().toString();
   System.out.println("TextView vehicleSrc"+itemSelected); // this is giving blank
   }
```

My error log -

```
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965):    at com.iddl.main.EntryFragment$13$2.onItemClick(UserFragment.java:907)
```

UPDATE:

I have defined the above textview in hidden field in xml-

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/vehicle_source"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="" 
     android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Now I am trying to set its value for each listview item as -

```
TextView vehicleSrc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_source);

if(isCondition1)
vehicleSrc.setText("Normal");
else
vehicleSrc.setText("Other");
end
```

Comment: Try Integer value = (Integer)view.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: You can also use String s = String.valueOf(view.getItemAtPosition(position));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973381/why-cannot-cast-integer-to-string-in-java
try this...

Comment: @Neil this is giving me the clicked item position but I am not able to get the clicked item hidden field value. See the update.

Comment: @SaurabhJain : `android:visibility="gone"` completely removes a view, it doesn't just hide it.

Comment: @Squonk yes basically my idea is to just set each item with some hidden value so that I can use that value on item click. So what you said is correct in my context. The problem is that, I am unable to get the set hidden field value on item click.

Comment: @SaurabhJain : Please read documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int) `gone` means the view doesn't exist at all - it's not just hidden. To see a view, make it `visible` but to hide it and still have it exist set it to `invisible`. If you set a view's visibility to `gone` you will never find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the hidden field value for the clicked item.

So, it should be

`String itemSelected =  ((TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_source)).getText().toString();`

instead of

```
String itemSelected =  ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_source)).getText().toString();
```

Complete code -

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
   //////////list view on click
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View arg1,
      int position, long arg3) {

    String itemSelected =  ((TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_source)).getText().toString();
   System.out.println("TextView vehicleSrc"+itemSelected);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast integer to string like what been warned here

```
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
03-20 12:47:08.742: E/AndroidRuntime(26965):    at com.iddl.main.EntryFragment$13$2.onItemClick(UserFragment.java:907)
```

if you want to to convert the integer to string you can use

```
Integer.toString( i )
```

like this one

```
String S = Integer.toString(view.getItemAtPosition(position)); //This line gives exception
      System.out.println("TextView vehicleSrc>>"+S);
```

and I think you should use android Log.i/Log.d/Log.e to log anything instead of system.out.println :)

Comment: there is a syntax error in your first line. It is giving - `The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Never cast anything without using **instancof**

   So your code ideally should be

   Object item =  view.getItemAtPosition(position);

   ```
      if(item instanceof String){
        //cast it
      }
   ```
2. Just check What type of adapter you have used.. getItem returns **TYPE** Adapter<**TYPE**>

Answer (score 0):

Try out this you will get the value of list list which is clicked

```
            String textOfSelectedItem;
                  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int id,
                long position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             textOfSelectedItem  =((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked is " + textOfSelectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```