# How to get value of a listview item and display it on AlertDialog?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that shows some information that I get from Github API, I set onItemClickListener for each item so I can display some information about them on alert dialog.

Before you flag this with Duplicate I want to say that none of these solution has worked for me [How to get the value of a Listview item which is clicked in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988378/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-listview-item-which-is-clicked-in-android)

I tried this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
      @Override public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<GithubRepo>> call,
          Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

          List<GithubRepo> repos = response.body();
          listViewRepo.setAdapter(new GitHubRepoAdapter(ReposActivity.this, repos));
        }
      }

listViewRepo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String val = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReposActivity.this);

        adb.setMessage(val).show();
      }
    });
```

But I get classCastException

> java.lang.ClassCastException: us.egek.repofinderforgithub.GithubRepo
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                                    at
>   us.egek.repofinderforgithub.ReposActivity$2.onItemClick(ReposActivity.java:63)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1162)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2953)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3708)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Adapter:

```
public class GitHubRepoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GithubRepo> {

  private Context context;
  private List<GithubRepo> values;

  public GitHubRepoAdapter(Context context, List<GithubRepo> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);

    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater =
          (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_pagination_text);

    GithubRepo item = values.get(position);
    String message = item.getName();
    textView.setText(message);

    return row;
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the complete logcat.

Comment: how are you setting your listView with a String array or it's a custom list

Comment: If you are using a custom adapter, post that class too.

Comment: Use list.get(position) inside the AlertBuilder

Comment: @Egek92 can you share the code where you're setting the list???

Comment: @NickIsaacs that won't work

Comment: Do you want the value in Adaptor or your class??

Comment: share your class code also

Comment: @Egek92 dont use it directly, use that to get your content, and then apply it to the DialogBuilder accordingly. list.get(position).getName() (this is according your adapter class code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
String val = (String) repos.get(position).getName();
```

Then you can use this value in your dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
String S = view.getContext().toString();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. All you're doing is running `toString()` on the context associated with a view. What does this accomplish? Please edit your answer  and elaborate.